# Reload a Store and populate Grid without redrawing Window

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid, and when i click on a row, and click the remove button. that record will get removed from the server and the grid will get updated. (If there are 10 records and if we delete 1, then there will be 9 records.)

This works for the 1st time, when we try to remove an item from the grid. Once the record gets removed and the grid gets updated. The `Window` that contains the grid gets drawn below the screen. I need to get rid of this.

How do i reload a `store` without redrawing the Window.

My code;

```
var ras = Ext.getStore('RemoveARowStore');

ras.on('load', function() {
       var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#window1 > #form1 > #grid1')[0];
    grid.getStore.load();
       grid.getView().refresh();

}, this, { single: true });
ras.load();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you update a store, the grid should automagically update the grid.

Therefore, you shouldnt have to do do `grid.getView.refresh()` which will be your offending line.

Furthermore, in the current snippet, actually watching for the `load` event, and actioning on it is kind of pointless. ( The grid will update itself anyway )

Comment: Even without that, it draws an empty window below the screen.

Comment: The whole `load` handler should be removed I think

Comment: This `grid.getStore.load();` ? If i remove it, then the grid doesn't get updated.

Comment: The entire `ras.on('load'` function is redundant. You don't need to do anything to your grid to display data from your store, you only need to load your store ( which you do here: `ras.load();` )

Comment: Ok, i got rid of it. But still the Window gets drawn at the bottom. :(

Comment: That's something else, not this code. Data will never* mess around with your layouts like this.

Comment: Any idea why this is hapenning ?

Comment: http://images.wikia.com/demigods/images/4/4a/Gremlins2-1-.jpg ? Seriously though, thats not something that can be salvaged from the current question. Post a new one, with your view + window in it.